# Simple termios transmitter

Tags: linux, arduino, arduino-uno, serial-communication, termios

I am having trouble sending data with termios libary

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int fd;
    fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    struct termios konzola;
    konzola.c_iflag = 0;
    konzola.c_oflag = 0;
    konzola.c_lflag = 0;
    konzola.c_cflag = 0;

    konzola.c_cflag = CS8 | CLOCAL | B9600 ;
    konzola.c_cc[VTIME]= 0;
    konzola.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
//  if(cfsetospeed(&konzola, B9600) != 0) printf("error\n");
    if(tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW, &konzola) != 0) printf("error\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        write(fd, argv[i], 1);
        tcdrain(fd);
        write(1, argv[i], 1);
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

On reciving side I get complete garbage. 
I am using Arduino Uno as reciving device.
Where did I screw up? :)

Comment: You do realize you are only sending the first character of each argument? Checked the example at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html#AEN125 ?

Comment: I actually need to send just one byte of data so that's not a problem. There are only examples for reading input.

Comment: Since arduino reboots after opening ttyACM device it is necessary to give it time to boot. sleep(3) after opening device solved problem. :)